# Best way to setup test cases that are "late" in a process

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, testing, junit, automated-tests

Best way of handling many test cases needing to navigate to a particular place before they run their asserts? For example a process has 5 steps and a test case needs to test a part of step 5, how can I set it up? Call the test case methods of the previous steps inside this test case, and do that for all test cases that test step 5?

Similarly, if a test case goes deep into the website - through many pages - should that navigation be re-written for every test case, or just call some test that already does that?

Any tips on this situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best way of handling many test cases needing to navigate to a particular place before they run their asserts? For example a process has 5 steps and a test case needs to test a part
>   of step 5, how can I set it up?

I would create a Transporter class / pattern that the test case can call to get to that state. That will make the navigation code reusable to other tests and not make the test too big/complicated. You can also use the `setUp()` methods in your xUnit testing frameworks which will be called before each test and place the navigator code there, if you need to use it for other tests.

> Similarly, if a test case goes deep into the website - through many
>   pages - should that navigation be re-written for every test case, or
>   just call some test that already does that?

I would extract that code into a helper class called Transporter and have the tests call it to easily navigate to the deep page in one method call.

I wrote about this and other test design patterns in a [conference paper](https://autotestguy.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/design-patterns-for-customer-testing.pdf) at the Pacific Northwest Software Quality Conference. Look for the Transporter pattern in that [paper](https://autotestguy.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/design-patterns-for-customer-testing.pdf).

Here's an example using a Transporter class where you have to login and navigate to the checkout page:

```
public class Transporter {
  public static void login() {
    //App specific code to navigate to login screen and login to the application
  }
  public static void gotoCheckout() {
    //App specific code to navigate to the checkout page
  }
}
```

Now your tests can just call this Transporter class to do the navigation for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BDD, such as JBehave (not sure if Cucumber has the same feature) where you have the Given, When, Then story (feature) structure in Gherkin syntax, you can actually use "GivenStories" feature which are like prequel test cases to set you up for your specific test case, exactly as you are describing.

There's nothing wrong, however, when using BDD to simply make multiple step scenarios leading up to the particular test case, i.e. first scenario logs-in, second scenario navigates to certain page, third scenario performs your actual test.

By writing it as a separate story (feature), however, you can re-use those as "GivenStories" in JBehave as a shortcut to get where you need to be without duplicating the steps.

Comment: While I'm using JUnit, before I get any other technologies, if a test case needs to go a few pages into the website, are there any "rules" against just navigating straight to that URL? I could guess that switching environments can cause an issue because the domain is different.

Comment: It all depends on whether or not the web site and/or testing process requires a login sequence, and therefore a "token."  If there is no login, there's no reason you can't just go directly to the page you need to test, otherwise a login sequence is the most common step one of any test case scenario and must be contiguous to get to where you need to go.